# Typescript generates file in incorrect directory

Tags: typescript, tsc

Here is fragment of my tsconfig.json that is used by typescript compiler to generate the JS file for my ts files. The files are picked from the typings directory and the generated sources are supposed to be created in **"./app/scripts"** directory. For some reason the typescript compiler generates the js scripts under the directory **"./app/scripts/typings"**. How can I force typescript to skip typings directory?

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "amd",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "listFiles": true,
    "diagnostics": true,
    "outDir": "./app/scripts"
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "./app/typings/**/*.ts",
    "./typings/main.d.ts",
    "./app/test/typings/**/*.ts"
  ], 
 "files": [
   "./app/typings/App.ts",
   "./app/typings/services/AService.ts"
  ]
```

I tried passing the --outDir parameter from the command line as well. It creates the js scripts under **"./app/scripts/typings"**

Comment: Move the tsconfig.json file into your app/typings folder instead.

Comment: what is the path to your tsconfig file relative to app?

Comment: It is in the same level as app directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `rootDir` option to `./app/typings` in your tsconfig.json file.
For more info: [rootDir](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/2772)

This should help.